# Find and replace full words only in JavaScript using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Say I had the following string:

```
var str = '(1 + foo + 3) / bar';
```

And I want to replace all strings just with the letter `'x'`. I tried:

```
str = str.replace(/\w/g, 'x');
```

This results in:

```
(x + xxx + x) / xxx
```

Instead, I would like the result to be:

```
(1 + x + 3) / x
```

How would I do this? How would I find just the words that don't have digits and replace the word to a single letter?

Comment: As others mentionned, use `/a-zA-Z/` instead, since `\w` contains numbers : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_wordchar.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use `[a-z]+` instead of `\w`? (Make sure to add the case-insensetive flag, or use `[a-zA-Z]` instead)

Answer (score 2):

```
str = str.replace(/\b[a-z]+\b/ig, 'x');
```

The `\b` matches a word boundary.  That way 'foo2' won't turn into 'x'.   As others mentioned `\w` includes numbers, but ALSO the underscore, so you won't want to use that.  The `i` modifier does case insensitive matching (so that you can read a little easier).

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
str = str.replace(/[a-z]+/ig, 'x');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `[a-zA-Z]` instead. `\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

```
str = str.replace(/[a-zA-Z]+/g, 'x');
```

Comment: Actually, `\w` is `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regex:

```
str = str.replace(/[a-z]+/ig, 'x');
```

**[a-z]** - To indicate that you are looking for any letter.

**+**   To indicate that you are looking for a combination (xxx).

**i**   To indicate that the text match can be case insensitive.

**g** - to indicate you are looking for all matches across the string.

or

you can use

```
   [a-zA-Z]
```

it will look for small letters a-z and capital letters A-Z. This is for use without the case modifier.